# How i support this video in IE8 Browsers using html5

Tags: html

how i use this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls="controls" 
       poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" 
       width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
            data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" 
            width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" 
               value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fclips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de%2Fbig_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" 
             src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" 
             width="640" height="360" 
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<p>
    <strong>Download video:</strong> 
    <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">MP4 format</a> | 
    <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Ogg format</a> | 
    <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">WebM format</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How i support this video in IE8 Browsers using html5 please help me.this video not support in IE8 Browsers.How i use this code

Comment: IE8?  HTML5?  You have a great sense of humor ;)  Look here: http://html5readiness.com/

Comment: i m new in IT feild.so i dont knoww this code. i m tranner.

Answer (score 1):

for IE8 you should upload it to Youtube or Vimeo and embed the video on your site. For you it is probably the best method in any browser anyway as you said this is all new to you.

So for instance: Login to Youtube, upload a video, and then click under the video on 'Share' and the 'Embed' (possibly in another language) Copy the code which you get and paste it in your HTML

Comment: Correct.  In other words, you *can't* support HTML5 "video" in IE8.  You need to do "something else".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Flash to play it, along with a player like JW Player or Flowplayer that you can embed on your page.